# CSV file contain double entries PHP SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql, fputcsv

I am using a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642136/export-query-result-as-csv-through-php) SO question to make a user download a csv file. However my CSV output contains double entries for each output e.g if expected output is 1,2,3,4,5 I get 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5. 
My query is okay since it outputs the actual results. 
Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablea,tableb WHERE tablea.Reference_No = tblb.Reference_No AND tablea.Reference_No = ? ";
```

This is my code to generate and download a copy of the query result

```
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$select,array($refno),array("Scrollable"=>SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC)) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
$count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
$openfile = fopen('../CSV/try.csv','w+');
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))

      {
         fputcsv($openfile, $row); 
    }

fclose($openfile);
$file ='../CSV/try.csv'; 
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
   // exit;
}
```

Using PHP and SQL Server. Is there anything wrong with the query or the way I am writing to the csv? Please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)
> >
> > Returns the next available row of data as an associative array, a numeric array, or **both** (the default).

(my emphasis)

Use

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
```

or

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)
```

Comment: Which OP would've seen by putting `var_dump($row)` in his loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query with:

```
SELECT * FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableb 
    ON tablea.Reference_No = tableb.Reference_No
WHERE tablea.Reference_No = ?
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableb 
    ON tablea.Reference_No = tableb.Reference_No
   AND tablea.Reference_No = ?
```

Comment: Tried that, same output. The query in my example and your examle work fine when I run them in SQL Management studio.